# The set of vectors whose coordinates are non-negative and sum to a number less than $1$

Tags: terminology, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let $n \in \{1,2,\dots\}$.

Consider the convex set consisting of all $(x_1,\dots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying:

- $x_i \geq 0$, $i \in \{1,\dots,n\}$
- $x_1 + \cdots + x_n \leq 1$

Does this set have a name?

More generally, suppose $\mathbf{V}$ is an $n$-dimensional, real vector space. Let $v_1, \dots, v_n$ be a basis for $\mathbf{V}$, and consider the convex set consisting of all $v \in \mathbf{V}$ of the form $v = x_1v_1 + \cdots + x_nv_n$, where the coefficients $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfy the two conditions listed above.

Does this set have a name?

Comment: The $n$-simplex?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Yes. Thank you.

Comment: This set is convex by its structure, so it is enough to satisfy your 2 conditions, you mentioned.

Comment: it is the *standard* $n$-simplex, denoted by $\Delta^n$